# Can stable Istotope analysis unambigously identify the Iberian Peninsula as the origin of signatures in human bones?

Tags: archaeology, anthropology

Is the Isotope signature (e.g. O and Sr) of the Iberian Penisula specific enough to proof a human spent decades of adult adult there? This is not about the teeth, only about bones.

Comment: Ultimately this looks to be more of a scientific question than a historical one, since the question is essentially about the reliability of a scientific process.

Comment: It is about the capabilities of a Archeological/Anthropological method, which i thought matched the tags.

Comment: It appears from the question that you're asking if these Isotopes leave a trace that can uniquely identify a person's remains as coming from that region. In which case, I'd say that was a question of the physical sciences. If, however, you're asking if the method of using Isotope signatures is generally valid for locating the origins of ancient human remains then you're moving into archaeology and anthropology.

Comment: Stable isotope analysis is well established as a method to identify the origin of remains in Archeology. I am asking if the Iberian Peninsula has a signature specific enough for this method to be applied.

Comment: That last rephrase of the question is far clearer to me - you might want to consider updating the question to indicate that.  On the other hand, you are way above my head, so perhaps I'm a bad judge.